# Como resolver este problema

Tags: javascript, jquery

Preciso fazer este código funcionar da forma que se conter a palavra na url eu mude para opção predefinida como segue:

```js
$('#servico').val(Sispostag.getParameterValue('servico'));  
var url = location.href;
if(url.indexOf('undefined')==-1) {                
    $('#servico').val(Sispostag.getParameterValue('servico'));
    var elementS = document.getElementById('servico');
    elementS.dispatchEvent(new Event('change'));
} else {
    $('#servico').val('123');
    var elementS = '123';
    elementS.dispatchEvent(new Event('change'));              
}
```

Porém sempre retorna este erro: Uncaught TypeError: elementS.dispatchEvent is not a function.

Alguém pode me ajudar a solucionar este erro?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se estás a usar jQuery, usa `.change()` para disparar o evento.

O erro em questão vem desta linha:

```
var elementS = '123';
```

e acontece é que estás a sobreescrever o valor da variável, e não do elemento. Depois quando chamas `dispatchEvent` é o mesmo que

```
123.dispatchEvent(new Event('change'))
```

e isso dá erro.

Sugestão de código:

```
var url = location.href;
if(url.indexOf('undefined')==-1) {                
    $('#servico').val(Sispostag.getParameterValue('servico')).change();
} else {
    $('#servico').val('123').change();           
}
```